# How to create 2 overlapped connected rings in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

See below. It's not a simple overlay of two rings

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  Use 2 `.overlay`s redrawing the top half of the first (`.orange`) circle to have it overlap the second (`.yellow`) circle.

[image: Overlapping rings running in simulator]

Note:  I added the `ringColors`, `lineWidth`, and `scale` as `let`s so that they can be easily experimented with:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        let ring1Color: Color = .orange
        let ring2Color: Color = .yellow
        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 40
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.7
        
        Circle()
            .scale(scale)
            .stroke(lineWidth: lineWidth)
            .foregroundColor(ring1Color)
            .offset(x: -lineWidth/2)
            .overlay(Circle()
                        .scale(scale)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: lineWidth)
                        .foregroundColor(ring2Color)
                        .offset(x: lineWidth/2))
            .overlay(Circle()
                        .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1)
                        .scale(scale)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: lineWidth)
                        .foregroundColor(ring1Color)
                        .offset(x: -lineWidth/2))
    }
}
```

---

Here I used `.foregroundColor(.blue)` for the last `.overlay` to reveal the *magic*.  The drawing order is:  1) `.orange`, 2) `.yellow`, 3) `.blue`

[image: Second overlay in blue to reveal drawing process]